# Why my rails application does not work with encoding ISO8859-1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding

SCENARIO:

I have a *ruby (2.2.3)* on *rails (4.2.4)* application, working on a *Firebird(2.5)* database through *activerecord-fb-adapter(1.0.2)*. This is a legacy database with ISO-8859-1 encoding, so I set up my database.yml file with encoding ISO-8859-1. Rails default encode is UTF-8, so I set up my application.rb file like this:

```
#config\application.rb    

config.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
```

Database.yml file:

```
#config\database.yml

default: &default
  adapter: fb
  encoding: ISO-8859-1
  create: false
  charset: ISO8859_1

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/cadastro.fdb
  username: sysdba
  password: masterkey
  host: localhost
```

ERROR:

The data coming from the database are ok, but when I tried to save data into the database or tried to show hard coded strings in a browser I receive a character error:

**browser error:**

```
code:

<th class="text-center">Data de Serviço</th>

output:

Data de ServiÃ§o
```

**database error:**

```
seeds:

MotoboyServiceType.where(:service_type => "REDAÇÃO").first_or_create

database:

REDAÃ‡ÃƒO
```

QUESTION:

How can I setup my application, so I can save the right data on database and display strings with right special characters?

Comment: Please add the contents of your `config/database.yml`. I have not used Firebird but most adapters usually take the encoding from there.

Comment: Added `config/database.yml` content.

Comment: Have you checked the character encoding of the html response? You can do this in the Chrome inspector under the network tab

Comment: Yes. This is the response header: `Content-Type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` .

Comment: I'd leave the encounter of the application as Utf-8. Also check what encoding your text editor is using for your files.

Comment: Yep, the problem was the html file encoding. I saved my html files as ISO-8859-1 and now everything is fine. Thanks.

Comment: However, my `db/seeds.rb` file still is `UTF-8`. If I try `seeds.rb` with `ISO-8859-1` rails raise an error: `invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)`.